# R - Vectorize a JSON call

Tags: json, r, ggplot2

Working with Mapquest directions API to plot thousands of routes using ggplot2 in R.

Basic code theory: Have a list of end locations and a single start location. For each end location, a call to fromJSON returns routing coordinates from Mapquest. From there, have already vectorized the assignment of coordinates (read as lists in lists) to the geom_path geom of ggplot2.

Right now, running this on a location set of ~ 1200 records takes ~ 4 minutes. Would love to get that down. Any thoughts on how to vectorize the call to fromJSON (which returns a list of lists)?

Windows 7, 64-bit, R 2.14.2

libraries: plyr, ggplot2, rjson, mapproj, XML

```
k = 0
start_loc        = "263+NORTH+CENTER+ST.,+MESA+ARIZ."
end_loc          = funder_trunc[,length(funder_trunc)]
route_urls       = paste(mapquest_baseurl, "&from=", start_loc, "&to=", end_loc, "&ambiguities=ignore", sep="")

for (n in route_urls) {

route_legs       = fromJSON(file = url(n))$route$legs[[1]]$maneuvers  
lats             = unlist(lapply(route_legs, function(x) return(x$startPoint[[2]])))
lngs             = unlist(lapply(route_legs, function(x) return(x$startPoint[[1]])))
frame            = data.frame(cbind(lngs, lats))
path_added       = geom_path(aes(lngs, lats), data = frame)
p                = p + path_added
k = k + 1
print(paste("Processed ", k, " of ", nrow(funder_trunc), " records in set.", sep=""))

}
```

Comment: `library(parallel)` and a suitable backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going out on a limb here since I don't use `rjson` or `mapproj`, but it seems like calling the server thousands of times is the real culprit. If the mapquest server doesn't have an API that allows you to send multiple requests in one go, you are in trouble. If it does, then you need to find out how to use/modify `rjson` and/or `mapproj` to call it...

As @Chase said, you might be able to call it in parallel, but the server won't like getting too many parallel requests from the same client - it might ban you. Btw, it might not even like getting thousands of serial requests in rapid succession from the same client either - but apparently your current code works so I guess it doesn't mind.